# Find largest sets of consecutive time periods

Tags: php, algorithm

I have an array of time periods on a given day, where some overlap, like so (start, end):

```
(10.00, 10.15) (11.00, 11.30) (11.30, 11.45) (11.45, 12.00) 
(11.45, 12.15) (12.15, 12.45) (13.20, 13.30) (14.15, 14.35) (14.35, 14.40)
```

I want to find the largest sets of consecutive time periods. In the above example there are 3 sets of consecutive times (shown below) but as the first set is a smaller 'alternative' to the second it should be ignored, so we are left with 2 and 3.

1. 11.00 - 11.30, 11.30 - 11.45, 11.45 - 12.00
2. 11.00 - 11.30, 11.30 - 11.45, 11.45 - 12.15, 12.15 - 12.45
3. 14.15 - 14.35, 14.35 - 14.40

One thing I must add: I would like to be able to specify a 'tolerance' that defines what consecutive means. In the above example consecutive means end time of first time period == start time of next time period, but it would be great to define consecutive as time periods that are '5 minutes apart', say.

Any ideas on how to do this in php or pseudocode would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Will these times always be in order and on the same day, or can they be in different orders and cross days?

Comment: Yes, they'll all be on the same day. In the case of time periods like 13.30 - 13.40 and 13.30 - 13.45, I guess 'in order' means smallest first? Either way, putting them in some sort of order wouldn't be difficult :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feels like a [Dynamic Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) kind of problem. I guess it can be solved as a graph problem, too.

If you turn your data into a graph: each period is a vertex, two vertices are connected if they are consecutive (use whatever tolerance level you want for this). All edges have the same weight. Now you need to find the [longest path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem) on that graph.

The longest path problem is an NP-complete, which is a bummer. However, with graphs without cycles, it is possible to solve this in polynomial time. Cool. Your graph is a-cyclic I hope (you don't round around entire days, right?). So, just put a weight of -1 on each  edge, and find the shortest graph. The last link I supplied also has a dynamic programming approach for this.

Comment: This is really helpful, thanks. I've implemented the algorithm given on the last link you supplied, but I'm having trouble adjusting it to get the actual path. It says I have to introduce a 'predecessor array' but I'm not sure what they mean?

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy [greedy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm) solution for this problem. First sort the time periods by start date ascending and if equal then by end date descending. Now loop through the time periods and keep track of your current set (it's leftmost and rightmost position). Here's the pseudo code (or some PHP / C++ / JS mix) -

```
bool comp(A, B) {
    if(A.start == B.start) return A.end > B.end;
    return A.start < B.start;
}

function getLongestSet( periods ) { //convert the times to integer first, period is pair of integers
    sort ( periods, comp);
    longestPeriod = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < periods.length; i++) {
        if(periods[i].start > curRight + TOLERANCE) { //start new set
            curLeft = periods[i].start, curRight = periods[i].end;
        }
        else { //expand current set
            curRight = max(curRight, periods[i].end);
        } 
        longestPeriod = max(longestPeriod, curRight - curLeft);
    }
    return longestPeriod;
}
```